# Rename the row and colnames in Matrix in R, length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I want to write a function to rename the matrix rows and columns.

My function is

```
changeMatrixName<- function(mat){
     nameRow<-vector(mode="character",length=nrow(mat))
     nameCol<-vector(mode="character",length=ncol(mat))
     nameCol<- colnames(mat)
     nameRow<- rownames(mat)
     #annotation[annotation$probeID==c("ILMN_1814092","ILMN_1668851"),]$symbol
     rowGeneName<-vector(mode="character",length=nrow(mat))
     colGeneName<-vector(mode="character",length=ncol(mat))


     rowGeneName<-annotation[annotation$probeID==c(nameRow),]$symbol
     colGeneName<-annotation[annotation$probeID==c(nameCol),]$symbol
     row.names(mat)<-rowGeneName
     col.names(mat)<-colGeneName
     return(mat)
  }
```

I have a test matrix like

```
      ILMN_1814092 ILMN_1805104 ILMN_2070570 ILMN_2232084 ILMN_1704579
 ILMN_1802380 4.972073e-03  0.016279737 0.0076933191 0.0214107369  0.001951975
 ILMN_1753196 2.222289e-04  0.080954797 0.0389565797 0.0220420297  0.002545084
 ILMN_1753830 1.657137e-05  0.009063726 0.0004676619 0.0008824427  0.007684124
```

When I run

test2<-changeMatrixName(test)

> Error in `rownames<-`(x, value) : 
>           length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
>           In addition: Warning message:
>           In annotation$probeID == c(nameRow) :
>              longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Do you mean `rownames` and `colnames` instead of `row.names` and `col.names`?

Comment: Yes, a kind of, I basically want to change the matrix's row names and column names @Thomas

Comment: @Thomas Do you know the answer ? please ?

Comment: Take the time to read my answer below.  I'm pretty sure I'm right about what you're doing wrong, though again, you'll get better answers if you provde data (including `annotation`).

Comment: I cannot upload data to this website... @BrodieG

Comment: just `dput(head(my.variable))` and post the results in the body of your question.  See **[reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to be sure without the data, but you almost certainly want something like:

```
rowGeneName <- annotation[match(nameRow, annotation$probeID),]$symbol
colGeneName <- annotation[match(nameCol, annotation$probeID),]$symbol
```

Right now, what you're using will overwrite your row and col vectors with a vector of length unlikely to be that of the original vectors.  Look at expression:

```
annotation$probeID==c(nameRow)
```

There, you are going to take the values in nameRow, and compare them value by value with those of probeID, irrespective of the order there in.  Those that happen to match will return TRUE, so you'll get a vector with however many matches you randomly happen to get by putting those two vectors side by side.

Another way to think about it, the expression above will only work as expected if `probeID` is of the exact same length as both `nameRow` and `nameColumn`, AND contains the exact same values in the same order as both `nameRow` and `nameColumn`, at which point you could just set `rowGeneName` and `colGeneName` directly equal to `annotation$symbol`.

`match` will actually search for the values of the first vector in the second, and return the index locations of the second vector that match.

Comment: I changed that to %in%, but the order is not wrong now...@BrodieG

Comment: You need to use `match`.  `%in%` is just a degenerate version of `match` that returns `TRUE` if a value in left operand is in right operand, but you need to know WHERE in the right operand the values from the left are, which you can do with `match`.  Look at the documentation for `%in%`, which is also the documentation for `match` (`%in%` is implemented with `match`).

Comment: Can I have your E-mail please ? @BrodieG

Comment: @ToBeGeek, to the extent this answered your question, please consider checking it off as the answer.  Thanks.